# error while creating object with no arguments using parameterized constructor with default arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have created a parameterized constructor with default arguments as follows:

```
Rectangle(int l=2,int b=2)
{
    setLength(l);
    setBreadth(b);
}
```

When I'm creating object like

```
Rectangle r;
```

It is taking both default arguments.

When

```
Rectangle r(10);
```

It takes another default argument.

But when

```
Rectangle r();
```

It's not working and throws and error,rather than taking both the default arguments.

Comment: A _**quick**_ search on the web would have given you plenty of answers. You're being victime of the [Most Vexing Parse (MVP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: @Enlico That only works if you already know about the "Most Vexing Parse"; and then you didn't need to do the search!

Comment: In my case, it is compiling and (probably) invoking default ctor (and no, I haven't explicitly provided one). (MSVC C++17)

Comment: @MikeHousky, the OP sees an error occurring probably on a line like `r.setLength(bla)` or something (not on the line `Rectangle r();`, because that is mis-interpreted, but ok), and that error is probably along the lines of `error: request for member ‘getLength’ in ‘r’, which is of non-class type ‘Rectangle()’`. If the OP searched for `"which is of non-class type" c++`, he would have got [relevant results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%22which+is+of+non-class+type%22).

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `Rectangle r();` you should be using just `Rectangle r;` for using default arguments. Using `Rectangle r();` gives error as use are kind on calling an object like a function.

Comment: *"as use are kind on calling an object like a function"* no idea what you're trying to tell us with this part of the sentence. I don't see this being close enough to what's actually causing the error to refrain from downvoting here.